# Spring MVC 3.2.8 application not binding Select object with the form

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an application based in the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. 
Using this approach in the JSP the value in linked

```
<form:select path="deviceKey" id="deviceSelectId" onchange="javascript:newWindowLocationAssignDevice(this.value);" >
                                        <form:option value="all" label="ALL"/>
                                        <form:options items="${allDeviceList}" itemValue="name" />
                                    </form:select>
```

But using this approach I always see the first option as selected independently of the value of the form

```
<form:select path="deviceKey" id="deviceSelectId" onchange="javascript:newWindowLocationAssignDevice(this.value);" >
                                            <form:option value="all" label="ALL"/>
                                            <c:forEach items="${allDeviceList}" var="deviceVar">                                                                                                    
                                                            <c:choose>
                                                                <c:when test="${!(deviceVar.name eq 'AWARDED') && !(deviceVar.name eq 'DRAFT') && !(deviceVar.name eq 'CANCELLED') && !(deviceVar.name eq 'IN_PROGRESS') && !(deviceVar.name eq 'REFUSED')}" >                                                              
                                                                    <option value="${deviceVar.name}" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<fmt:message  key="${deviceVar.key}" /></option>
                                                                </c:when>
                                                                <c:otherwise>
                                                                    <option value="${deviceVar.name}"><fmt:message  key="${deviceVar.key}" /></option>
                                                                </c:otherwise>
                                                            </c:choose>                                                                                                                                                                         

                                                    </c:forEach> 
                                        </form:select>
```